# C# - error while accessing a simple property of activeX control in js - stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, javascript, c#-3.0, activex, stack-overflow

I am creating an `ActiveX` object in `javascript`, and calling a method on the object. This works perfectly fine. But, if I try to access a `property` of the activeX control (or return a value from the called method), the browser crashes (message : **IE has stopped working**). In the details section, it says that `System.StackOverflowException` was not caught. 
The C# code is :

```
interface IScreenshot{
   int data {get; set;}
}

 public class ScreenShot : UserControl, IScreenShot, IObjectSafety
    {
       public int data
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data=13;
            }
        }
   }
```

The js code to access it is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 var x = new ActiveXObject("Try1.ScreenShot");
 var value = x.data;
</script>
```

Detailed error is :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: iexplore.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 9.0.8112.16448
  Problem Signature 03: 4fecf1b7
  Problem Signature 04: Try1
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 507399f0
  Problem Signature 07: 5
  Problem Signature 08: 0
  Problem Signature 09: System.StackOverflowException
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.11
  Locale ID: 1033
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
 public int data
 {
    get
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

In order to return the data, you... return the data. Bang. You need to have a *field* to store the value.

Your setter also ignores the incoming value, which is distinctly odd.

Assuming you don't really need any *logic* for your property, you can use an automatically implemented property - ideally having changed the name to follow .NET naming conventions:

```
public int Data { get; set; }
```

(Ideally you'd give it a more *meaningful* name at the same time...)

Note that this has nothing to do with Javascript - you'd see the same problem with that property implementation in a pure C# app.

Comment: "In order to return the data, you... return the data." - causing the StackOverflow exception. Great !!